# using request response as a global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I'm trying to initializing body of request function to a **global variable** but useless.
It's returning blank output.
Kindly help me to access the body outside the function.

[image: code image]

Comment: could you show us some code ? the result expected ? and what you get ?

Comment: there's about link of code image. you can check

Comment: The last console.log statement will execute _before_ the callback function of `request` is called.

Comment: console.log is working perfectly inside the request function but not outside.

Comment: @BilalSheikh avoid using image on stack overflow, use 3x` to show us code

Comment: If you're relying on global state you're probably doing something wrong. Just do what you want to do inside the request.

Comment: _"console.log is working perfectly inside the request function but not outside"_ - you didn't get an idea of why that is from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68649434/using-request-response-as-a-global-variable#comment121322123_68649434)? Callback function of `request` is invoked asynchronously, i.e. _after_ your script has finished executing. `console.log` statement at the end of your code is executed _before_ the callback function initializes `gdata`.

Comment: @Yousaf then how can I wait until call back ?

Comment: Move the `console.log` inside the callback function. Do what you want to do with `gdata` inside the callback function. Even better approach is to directly use `body` and get rid of `gdata`. See the link to another stackoverflow question linked in one of my earlier comments. You can't do what you are trying to do - at-least not in a reliable way.

Comment: but i want to store this to another variable to use it later

Comment: Use it where? What do you want to do with `gdata`?

Comment: I want to get **body** from request function and assign it to **gdata**

Comment: I can see that. My question is what do you want to do with `gdata`?

Comment: body will return json data. I will store it to gdata variable. then i will use parse json data to js object. after this, i will use this variable to show data on browser in an organized way.

Comment: You can do all that inside the callback function or create a function and call that function from inside of the callback function.

Comment: I'm yet confused but thanks dear <3

Comment: Just do with the `body` variable what you want intended to do with `gdata`. Forget `gdata` and the last console.log statement. Inside the callback function, parse the json and display it in the browser.

Comment: okay dear, I got it